# Good way to convert integer YYYYMMDD into java.util.Date with local time zone

Tags: java, date, jodatime, date-conversion

I understand this question could look like FAQ subject but critical things here is time zone and performance. I have integer YYYYMMDD date (20150131 is example). Here is good 'almost working' solution:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import java.util.Date;

// ...

public Date extract(final int intDate) {
    Date result = null;

    try {
        result = new DateTime(
                intDate / 10000,
                (intDate / 100) % 100,
                intDate % 100,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0).toDate();

    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // Log failure
    }
    return result;
}
```

'almost' is because having 0x0126810d and EET (UTC+2 / +3 when DST) time zone I receive:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal instant due to time zone
>   offset transition: 1930-06-20T22:00:00.000

At least using JODA 1.6. I cannot switch easily.
But I'd like it to be `1930-06-21T00:00:00.000+02:00` and I don't care about UTC representation.

1. Is it possible at all (can `java.util.date` store such date)?
2. OK, any better high performance way to achieve this (JODA is just remedy here, not critical)?

Yes, I understand this time does not exist:

```
roman@node4:$ zdump -v Europe/Kiev | grep 1930
Europe/Kiev  Fri Jun 20 21:59:59 1930 UTC = Fri Jun 20 23:59:59 1930 EET isdst=0 gmtoff=7200
Europe/Kiev  Fri Jun 20 22:00:00 1930 UTC = Sat Jun 21 01:00:00 1930 MSK isdst=0 gmtoff=10800
```

Comment: I copied your function (made it static). I used `TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EET"));` followed by `System.out.println( extract(0x0126810d));`. I do not get any exception. What version of Java and Joda are you using?

Comment: 1.6 and I cannot change this at least in near future.

Comment: Any particular reason why you do this with Joda rather than `Calendar`?

Comment: Works for me too - outputting Sat Jun 21 00:00:00 EET 1930 with Joda 2.7.  Following your edit re Joda 1.6 - I downloaded that and tried it.  Still no exception - it outputs "Sat Jun 21 00:15:36 EET 1930".  I don't know where the extra minutes come from...  I wonder if this is something strange to do with system setup. I'm using Windows 8, Java 7, Joda - the two versions quoted above.  I did find this article - calling into question performance of pre 2.1 Joda versions around timezone http://java-performance.info/joda-time-performance/

Comment: I got 15:36 with joda 1.6.2 on a mac with java 6. So, not a system setup. Seems like some kind of a bug in joda. 2.1 does work as expected, returning midnight in EET.

Comment: The answer is probably my system timezone set to EET (Kyiv/Ukraine). Just checked fails with 2.7.

Comment: Perhaps there's a difference in the timezone file. Is your system Linux? Can you run `zdump -v Europe/Kiev | grep 1930`?

Comment: roman@node4:$ zdump -v Europe/Kiev | grep 1930
Europe/Kiev  Fri Jun 20 21:59:59 1930 UTC = Fri Jun 20 23:59:59 1930 EET isdst=0 gmtoff=7200
Europe/Kiev  Fri Jun 20 22:00:00 1930 UTC = Sat Jun 21 01:00:00 1930 MSK isdst=0 gmtoff=10800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally got the following fragment and it works most close to my expectations. Like SDF but many times faster - like no string parsing just to get digits:

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;

public static Date toDateJoda(int intDate) {
    LocalDate ldt = new LocalDate(
        intDate / 10000,
        (intDate / 100) % 100,
        intDate % 100);

    DateTime dt = ldt.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay();
    return dt.toDate();
}
```

Parses everything and gets next valid date / time for cases like mine.

Answer (score 2):

### java.time and LocalDate

No matter if using Joda-Time (as in your question) or java.time, the modern Java date and time API, I believe that the solution to your problem is using `LocalDate`. I suggest that you simply stick to this and neither use `org.joda.time.DateTime` nor `java.util.Date`. In particular not the latter, it was always poorly designed and is now long outdated.

I am presenting to ways.

```
    int intDate = 19300621; // 0x0126810d

    String asString = String.valueOf(intDate);
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(asString, DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);

    System.out.println(date);
```

> 1930-06-21

I find this code clearer to read than the code doing divisions and modulo operations. It’s not as efficient, but for more than 19 out of 20 cases this should be no concern. If you like the divisions, you can of course do them with java.time too:

```
    int year = intDate / 10000;
    int monthDay = intDate % 10000;
    int month = monthDay / 100;
    int day = monthDay % 100;
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
```

**If you do need a java.util.Date** for a legacy API not yet upgraded to java. time (or Joda-Time), convert like this (no matter which of the above conversions you used):

```
    Instant asInstant = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
    Date oldfashionedDate = Date.from(asInstant);
    System.out.println(oldfashionedDate);
```

Output when my default time zone is set to Europe/Zaporozhye:

> Sat Jun 21 01:00:00 EET 1930

(We notice that we get 01:00:00 because of transition to summer time (DST). The time of 00:00:00 didn’t exist on this day in this time zone.)

### If still using Joda-Time

If you are still using Joda-Time, your own answer using `toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()` is just fine.

PS I reproduced your problem with Joda-Time 2.9.9, my time zone set to Europe/Zaporozhye and your integer of 19300621 (don’t know why you gave it as hex, 0x0126810d). I got an exception similar to yours: `org.joda.time.IllegalInstantException: Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (daylight savings time 'gap'): 1930-06-21T00:00:00.000 (Europe/Zaporozhye)`.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
result = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: BTW GregorianCalendar can help better but it has anyway 'current' moment initialization and try to get him things like -1,-1,-1.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I managed to replicate your problem, by doing:

```
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Kiev"));
    System.out.println( extract(0x0126810d));
```

(Previously I tried that with "EET", but apparently that gets a different time zone altogether)

I get an illegal argument exception, though the date it mentions is a bit different. This could be because of my version of Joda.

```
Illegal instant due to time zone offset transition (daylight savings time 'gap'): 1930-06-21T00:00:00.000 (Europe/Kiev)
```

Well, the way to solve it is not to be in the Europe/Kiev zone, at least for the sake of the Joda conversion:

```
public static Date extract(final int intDate) {
    Date result = null;
    DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(2);

    try {
        result = new DateTime(
                intDate / 10000,
                (intDate / 100) % 100,
                intDate % 100,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                0,
                tz).toDate();

    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This would avoid the error. You could move the `tz` variable definition and initialization to a field if you wish to improve performance in case you are calling the `extract` method a lot of times.

Mind you that when you print the resulting `Date` object using the default date format, which in turn uses the default time zone (Europe/Kiev), the result would be:

```
Sat Jun 21 01:00:00 EET 1930
```

You can print it properly with:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
fmt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2"));


System.out.println(fmt.format( extract(0x0126810d)));
```

But maybe if you don't want to take DST into consideration, you should just work with the dates as if they were UTC. It depends what you want to do with them, really.

One last note: it's really easy to achieve the same result with `Calendar`:

```
public static Date extract2(final int intDate) {
    cal.set(intDate / 10000, ( intDate / 100 ) % 100 - 1, intDate % 100);
    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Where `cal` is a `Calendar` instance set in a field to avoid repeatedly creating and clearing it:

```
public static final Calendar cal;
static {
    cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.clear();
}
```

(Mind multithreading, though).

Not sure about the performance problems you mentioned, and how critical the difference is.