# I have a date in int format DDMMYYYY, how can I separate day and month and year

Tags: java, date, datetime-format

```
int date1 = 22092021
int date2 = 03122021
```

I want to know which date is older
assuming each month has 30 days

Comment: `int date2 = 03122021` you're in for a surprise with this one, since that's an octal number. In other words, why are these integers to begin with?

Comment: Is this input really an integer or a string?

Comment: for example date1 = 22092021 means day 22, month 09, year 2021

Comment: And note: just coming here and dropping your requirements isn't appreciated by most people. To receive better reception, always include your OWN efforts. We help you solving problems, we dont do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: @Edgero30 - You should collect the input as a `String` instead of an `int`.

Comment: Your question is similar to (not the same as) [Good way to convert integer YYYYMMDD into java.util.Date with local time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910196/good-way-to-convert-integer-yyyymmdd-into-java-util-date-with-local-time-zone). I think you can find some helpful inspiration there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in comments, it's most likely that input might be coming as string. You can easily parse `Date` from string like this:

```java
private static Date getDate(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");
    return simpleDateFormat.parse(dateStr);
}
```

Then you can do something like this to check which date is older:

```java
String date1 = "22092021";
String date2 = "03122021";

Date d1 = getDate(date1);
Date d2 = getDate(date2);

if (d1.compareTo(d2) < 0) {
    System.out.println("d1 is older than d2");
} else if (d1.compareTo(d2) > 0) {
    System.out.println("d2 is older than d1");
} else {
    System.out.println("both are equal");
}
```

In case you're interested in extracting day, month and year from your `Date` instance, you can create a small utility method to convert it to `Calendar` like this:

```java
private static Calendar toCalendar(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    return cal;
}
```

Then you can extract it with `Calendar::get` methods like this:

```java
Calendar c1 = toCalendar(d1);
System.out.printf("%d %d %d\n", c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), c1.get(Calendar.MONTH), c1.get(Calendar.YEAR));

Calendar c2 = toCalendar(d2);
System.out.printf("%d %d %d\n", c2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), c2.get(Calendar.MONTH), c2.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the obvious problems with this representation (see comments) the parts could be separated like this:

```
int y = date % 10000
date /= 10000
int m = date % 100
int d = date / 100
```